# How can a search engine derive structured data from an html page?

Tags: html, search, seo, search-engine, semantic-web

How does the system determine what html element contains data about which variable?

HTML5 allows people to tag their elements like

```
<div data-productname=BMW>BMW</div>
```

but how do search engines do it with older websites?

Answer (score 5):

The `data-` attributes are for authors to use for their own purposes, for “private use.” They should be expected to be ignored by browsers, search engines, and other software, except software specifically tailored to use them according to the private meanings assigned to them.

So any search engine that uses them is broken.

Generally, search engines do not try to determine what html element contains data about which variable. They operate on the text content of pages, and to some extent on some markup elements (like `h1`, which may be assumed to have higher relative relevance than other text).

Systems have been and are being developed for low-level metadata, which may use e.g. class attributes with special names or some new attributes. Some major search engines have expressed their support to this in some ways, see especially http://www.schema.org . But in practice, they seems to do this mainly to very large web sites, according to principles that have not been disclosed in public.

Answer (score 0):

Semantic markups like rdfa and microformats have support for product schemas.

Many product websites also expect you to provide a feed with your product data in a certain format.

Answer (score 0):

> How do they derived structured information?

They will parse the page's html elements and store them into data structures that are as diverse as the search engines themselves.

Some search engines will index meta information, but major ones have started to disregard the meta tags.

Most search engines take into account:

- Plain text information
- Proximity information of words and phrases
- Links that reference similar information
- Page titles

Here's an interesting info graphic that may answer any other questions you have:
http://ppcblog.com/how-google-works/

Answer (score 0):

Until the semantic web grows up (I'm not sure, when and in what final form it will occur), there are indeed some problems in retrieving meanings from pure HTML. If a publisher of an (not necessarily HTML) page does not use some standard way of saying which data is what, you (as a search engine's party) should deduce semantics yourself. First, as the mention of "not HTML" pages is fresh, there exist sites which host XML pages accompanied with XSL for rendering in browsers. XML gives you more semantic information, if you know the schema or DTD being used. (By the way, Wikipedia does provide archives with their articles in XML.) If XML is not used or undocumented, so to speak, there is a second approach, which requires experts and programmers. The experts are people who analyse content and decide which parts of HTML page should be treated as templates storing specific information. For example, you can elaborate templates for search results from html-pages of some internet catalog and extract categories, ratings and other stuff for each listed site. These templates can be parsed from and detected in web-pages using an arbitrary programming language (C++, Python, etc.). After this you can apply a well-known `map-reduce` algorithm or other means to index the extracted data by key-value pairs. If you look at which sites are normally processed in such templatized way, you'll see they are big, public, and well-structured (with little changes in the structure over time). This makes sense to write and reuse templates. Of course, the same experts should monitor data extraction quality and edit templates if something is changed in corresponding site markup. And the third resource of meanings are vocabularies. For example, if you have a comprehensive base of geographic names, bussines companies (including a subcategory of automanufacturers), and other categorized stuff, you can hit them in semantic index almost automatically. I say "almost", because you should weight each hit in regard to contextual words - in a document about computers, `Java` is most likely about the programming language, and on a site of a travel agency, it is more probable an island.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular example, you should consider using RDFa to describe the data in your HTML document. You'll notice that I don't mention using Microdata and thats because RDFa can provide richer, more faceted data to a crawler. In your particular case, you could leverage the GoodRelations vocabulary (for ecommerce, products and services), the schema.org vocabulary (borrows from GoodRelations) and the Vehicle Sales Ontology (for automobiles). Please see working example below:

```
<div prefix="sc: http://schema.org/ gr: http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1# vso: http://purl.org/vso/ns#" 
     typeof="vso:Automobile gr:ProductOrServiceModel sc:Product" 
     resource="http://dbpedia.org/page/BMW_1_Series">
    <span property="gr:name sc:name">BMW 1 Series</span>
</div>
```

This exposes your data in every facet, making it understandable and consumable by almost any search engine (including Semantic Search engines). Additionally, you can also link to resources in DBPedia (Wikipedia Database) by using the same URI's to identify your instances.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways this kind of information can be extracted:

- Structured information can be provided explicitly using e.g. RDF or other metadata description languages, like those from [schema.org](http://www.schema.org).
- Google may have contracts with price comparison services and/or big individual players in the e-commerce business, which allow them to retrieve structured information from their databases or using special protocols.
- There are some popular e-commerce engines, so if they learn how to extract data from a particular engine's HTML, they can handle a large number of individual shops that use that engine.
- Heuristics may be applied in order for the spider to recognize pages which look like product descriptions and to automatically extract some structured information. Many elements may be easily recognized, e.g. the product name may be some text at the top of the page placed in H1 tags, and if there's a table , it may look for common property names such as "price" or "color" and try to find matching values somewhere near a table (it's relatively easy to recognize prices based on a simple pattern, same goes for many other fields). As you know, Google can extract information about a web page's navigation menu automatically (without any help from the page itself), based on heuristics of what a typical page with a navigation menu looks like. Most shop pages also have typical layouts and product pages have some typical properties, so it is certainly possible to build similar heuristics for detecting product data.
- Now that Google recently started rendering web pages with full Chrome rendering engine, and even running JavaScript, they are able to generate the whole page's DOM model, meaning they can apply "visual" heuristics as well, like "product name is some text at the top of page, written in a bigger font that the surroundings" etc. One of my company's products performs similar analyses, so I know it is quite well possible (though computationally expensive).